# PersistenceContext lifecycle in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, hikaricp

I'm trying to undestand, how the Persistence Context in Spring Boot application works. I use Spring Data, Hibernate and Hikari.

I can't find out, when the `PersistenceContext` is created and when it is closed. According to several articles, for example this one https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-persistence-context or this one https://dzone.com/articles/how-does-spring-transactional the `PersistenceContext` lifecycle is the same as the `EntityManager` lifecycle. So I was wondering, when the `EntityManager` is actually created and more important when it is closed and most important if it is closed at the end of the transaction. According to what I found, the enum `PersistenceContextType.java` decides what `PersistenceContext` will I have. The `PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION` should be default, should cause that the `SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler` is used as the implementation of the `EntityManager` and should be closed at the end of the transaction, while `PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED` should outlive the transaction and should cause that the `ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler` is being used. So I attempted to prove it by debugging and I found following.

1. `PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED` is not being evaluated anywhere. There is some usage in `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java`, but the breakpoint never stopped there in my integration tests.
2. Sometimes `SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler#invoke` and sometimes `ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler#invoke` is being invoked, which doesn't tell me what kind of `EntityManager` does it use.
3. In some occasions I even found `SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler` wrapping `ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler`.

The question is - how is it determined, if the `PersistenceContext` is closed at the end of transaction or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED` is not being evaluated anywhere. There is some usage in `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java`, but the breakpoint never stopped there in my integration tests.

You will hit the breakpoint when you have the following field declaration in any of your beans:

```
@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

> The question is - how is it determined, if the PersistenceContext is closed at the end of transaction or not?

Interesting question. If you dig through the Spring code a little, you will note that `SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler` calls `EntityManagerFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalEntityManager()`. The method registers a transaction synchronization for the returned `EntityManager` instance:

```
TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(
                                new TransactionalEntityManagerSynchronization(emHolder, emf, transactionData, false));
```

That synchronization is what closes the `EntityManager` after the transaction:

```
protected void releaseResource(EntityManagerHolder resourceHolder, EntityManagerFactory resourceKey) {
            closeEntityManager(resourceHolder.getEntityManager());
        }
```

You'll also note that `ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler` does no such thing.